# use model object, e.g. panelmodel, to flag data used

Tags: r, plm, broom

Is it possible in some way to use a *fit object*, specifically the regression object I get form a `plm()` model, to flag observations, in the data used for the regression, if they were in fact used in the regression. I realize this could be done my looking for complete observations in my original data, but I am curious if there's a way to use the fit/reg object to flag the data.

Let me illustrate my issue with a minimal working example,

First some packages needed,

```
# install.packages(c("stargazer", "plm", "tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(plm); library(stargazer); library(tidyverse)
```

Second some data, this example is drawing heavily on Baltagi (2013), table 3.1, found in `?plm`,

```
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
dta <- Grunfeld
```

now I create some semi-random missing values in my data object, `dta`

```
dta[c(3:13),3] <- NA; dta[c(22:28),4] <- NA; dta[c(30:33),5] <- NA
```

final step in the data preparation is to create a data frame with an index attribute that describes its individual and time dimensions, using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse),

```
dta.p <- dta %>% group_by(firm, year)
```

Now to the regression

```
plm.reg <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = dta.p, model = "pooling")
```

the results, using [stargazer](/questions/tagged/stargazer),

```
stargazer(plm.reg, type="text") # stargazer(dta, type="text")
#> ============================================
#>                  Dependent variable:    
#>              ---------------------------
#>                          inv            
#> ----------------------------------------
#> value                 0.114***          
#>                        (0.008)          
#>                                         
#> capital               0.237***          
#>                        (0.028)          
#>                                         
#> Constant             -47.962***         
#>                        (9.252)          
#>                                         
#> ----------------------------------------
#> Observations             178            
#> R2                      0.799           
#> Adjusted R2             0.797           
#> F Statistic   348.176*** (df = 2; 175)  
#> ===========================================
#> Note:        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Say I know my data has 200 observations, and I want to find the 178 that was used in the regression.

I am speculating if there's some vector in the `plm.reg` I can (easily) use to crate a flag i my original data, `dta`, if this observation was used/not used, i.e. the semi-random missing values I created above. Maybe some [broom](/questions/tagged/broom) like tool.

I imagine something like,

```
dta <- dta %>% valid_reg_obs(plm.reg)
```

The desired outcome would look something like this, the new element is the vector `plm.reg` at the end, i.e.,

```
dta %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 200 x 6
#>     firm  year   inv value capital plm.reg
#>  * <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>  
#>  1     1  1935   318  3078    2.80 T      
#>  2     1  1936   392  4662   52.6  T      
#>  3     1  1937    NA  5387  157    F      
#>  4     1  1938    NA  2792  209    F      
#>  5     1  1939    NA  4313  203    F      
#>  6     1  1940    NA  4644  207    F      
#>  7     1  1941    NA  4551  255    F      
#>  8     1  1942    NA  3244  304    F      
#>  9     1  1943    NA  4054  264    F      
#> 10     1  1944    NA  4379  202    F      
#> # ... with 190 more rows
```

Update, I tried to use [broom](/questions/tagged/broom)'s `augment()`, but unforunatly it gave me the error message I had hoped would create some flag,

```
# install.packages(c("broom"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(broom)
augment(plm.reg, dta) 
#> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
#>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 200, 178
```

Comment: In case you do not need the link to your original data, just look at `plm.reg$model` to get the observations used in estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector is `plm.reg$residuals`.  Not sure of a nice `broom` solution, but this seems to work:

```
library(tidyverse)

dta.p %>% 
as.data.frame %>% 
rowid_to_column %>% 
mutate(plm.reg = rowid %in% names(plm.reg$residuals))
```

for people who use the class `pdata.frame()` to create an index attribute that describes its individual and time dimensions, you can us the following code, this is from another Baltagi in the `?plm`,

```
# == Baltagi (2013), pp. 204-205
data("Produc", package = "plm")
pProduc <- pdata.frame(Produc, index = c("state", "year", "region"))
form <- log(gsp) ~ log(pc) + log(emp) + log(hwy) + log(water) + log(util) + unemp
Baltagi_reg_204_5 <- plm(form, data = pProduc, model = "random", effect = "nested")

pProduc %>% mutate(reg.re = rownames(pProduc) %in% names(Baltagi_reg_204_5$residuals)) %>% 
            as_tibble() %>% select(state, year, region, reg.re)
#> # A tibble: 816 x 4
#>    state       year  region reg.re
#>    <fct>       <fct> <fct>  <lgl> 
#>  1 CONNECTICUT 1970  1      T     
#>  2 CONNECTICUT 1971  1      T     
#>  3 CONNECTICUT 1972  1      T     
#>  4 CONNECTICUT 1973  1      T     
#>  5 CONNECTICUT 1974  1      T     
#>  6 CONNECTICUT 1975  1      T     
#>  7 CONNECTICUT 1976  1      T     
#>  8 CONNECTICUT 1977  1      T     
#>  9 CONNECTICUT 1978  1      T     
#> 10 CONNECTICUT 1979  1      T     
#> # ... with 806 more rows
```

finally, if you are running the first Baltagi without index attributes, i.e. unmodified example from the help file, the code should be,

```
Grunfeld %>% rowid_to_column %>% 
    mutate(plm.reg = rowid %in% names(p$residuals)) %>% as_tibble()
```

Comment: Thanks, David. This is exactly what I hope to find. Thanks again!